# Different class types as RequestBody depending on RequestParam provided in a Spring Boot Controller?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have a controller which takes in a request parameter and a body. The request body can be of various class types depending on the type of parameter. Currently I am using `JsonNode` for the body which works fine. Looks like this :

```
@PostMapping()
public ResponseEntity<Response> save(@RequestParam("request type") RequestProcess process,
                               @Valid @RequestBody JsonNode requestJson) {
```

I want to know whether it's possible to provide the body with the class type depending on the param provided. If yes how do I do it?

If this is not possible in REST, is there a chance I might be able to do this using GraphQL. I don't know much about GraphQL still researching.

Comment: No, we can not do that.

Comment: Sure ok. Also I dont know much about GraphQL. Can it be a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The nearer you can reach is by using generics

```
class Controller < T > {
  @PostMapping("/save")
  ResponseEntity < Response > save(@RequestBody T requestJson) {}
}
```

Comment: I am already using JsonNode as a generic. Thanks for the answer though.